# Prove that a set $S$ is disconnected iff a continuous function $f$ takes only the values $2$ and $3$ on $S$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Prove that a set $S$ is disconnected iff a continuous function $f$ takes only the values $2$ and $3$ on $S$.

My approach :

First prove that if $f$ is continuous $S$ is disconnected; if $f$ takes only the values $2$ and $3$. Assume $S$ is connected, and let $p,q  \epsilon S$ such that $f(p)=2$ and $f(q)=3$
By mean value there is $f(p)<c<f(q)$ such that for some $t \epsilon S$ $f(t)=c$. But we know that $f$ takes on values $2$ and $3$ only, so there is a contradiction, therefore $S$ is disconnected.

Conversely try to prove that if $S$ disconnected $f$ is continuous; if $f$ takes only the values $2$ and $3$. I couldn't try to come up with a proof here, could someone help me out please?

Comment: The statement "if S is disconnected then a continuous function f takes only the values 2 and 3" is wrong

Comment: Just define $ f \left ( x \right ) = 2 \forall x \in S $.

Comment: The problem is ill-stated. What's true is that *if a continuous real function on $S$ takes only the values $2$ and $3$ (and both of them), then $S$ is disconnected*. If $S$ is disconnected it's easy to find a continuous real function on $f$ that doesn't take either value. For instance, the constant function $0$.

Comment: @egreg Wouldn't my first proof prove your statement? 
I believe the statement is false but it is in the book so I wondered,
I believe if the statement is corrected by yours my proof is enough, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume $S$ is a metric space (in particular a subset of the reals).

It's impossible to prove that if $S$ is disconnected then a continuous real function on $S$ takes the values $2$ and $3$ and only them, because it's clearly false. Consider the function $f\colon S\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=2$, for all $x\in S$.

Nonetheless, the converse is true. Suppose $f\colon S\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and its image is $\{2,3\}$. Then the sets
$$
A=\{x\in S:f(x)=2\}
\qquad
B=\{x\in S:f(x)=3\}
$$
make a disconnection of $S$ (verify the details).

What you can say is that if $S$ is disconnected, then *there exists* a continuous real function on $S$ with image equal to $\{2,3\}$. Indeed, if $A$ and $B$ make a disconnection of $S$, then
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
2 & \text{if $x\in A$}\\[4px]
3 & \text{if $x\in B$}
\end{cases}
$$
defines a continuous function on $S$ with the required property (verify it).